# Edit properties of Existing Object in ListBox items C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, listboxitem

I am trying to fetch searched inventories and on button click, adding it to the listbox in my orders from unsing the code below. The Listbox items are a list of objects called OrderItems. After fetching searched result I check if the item existed in the ListBox and just add Quantity property of existing item else add as new item. The logic works fine and it is looping and recognizes the existing item, however, the Quanity text of the item in ListBox does not change and always shows 1.
I am using

```
listBoxItems.DisplayMember = "ItemTitleWithQtyPrice";
listBoxItems.ValueMember = "ItemInventoryId";
```

And the Code

```
private void AddItemsToListBox(OrderItem item)
    {            
        Boolean itemExists = false;
        listBoxItems.DisplayMember = "ItemTitleWithQtyPrice";
        listBoxItems.ValueMember = "ItemInventoryId";

        if (listBoxItems != null && listBoxItems.Items.Count > 0)
        {                
            if (listBoxItems.ValueMember != null)
            {                    
                foreach (OrderItem it in listBoxItems.Items)
                {
                    if(it.ItemInventoryId == item.ItemInventoryId)
                    {
                        it.Quantity = it.Quantity + 1;
                        it.CGSTAmount = it.CGSTAmount * it.Quantity;
                        it.SGSTAmount = it.CGSTAmount * it.Quantity;
                        if (it.DiscountAmount > 0)
                        {
                            it.DiscountAmount = it.DiscountAmount * it.Quantity;
                        }
                        it.Total = it.GrossPricePerUnit * it.Quantity;
                        item.ItemTitleWithQtyPrice = item.ItemTitle + " Quantity " + item.Quantity + " Total Price: ₹ " + item.Total;
                        listBoxItems.Update();
                        itemExists = true;

                        GrandTotal = GrandTotal + it.Total;
                        TotalDiscount = TotalDiscount + it.DiscountAmount;
                        TotalTaxAmount = TotalTaxAmount + it.GGSTAmount;

                        order.GrandTotal = GrandTotal;
                        order.TotalDiscount = TotalDiscount;
                        order.TaxAmount = TotalTaxAmount;
                    }       
                }

                if (!itemExists)
                {
                    item.Quantity = 1;
                    item.Total = item.GrossPricePerUnit * item.Quantity;
                    item.DiscountAmount = item.DiscountAmount * item.Quantity;
                    item.GGSTAmount = (item.SGSTAmount + item.CGSTAmount) * item.Quantity;
                    item.ItemTitleWithQtyPrice = item.ItemTitle + " Quantity " + item.Quantity + " Total Price: ₹ " + item.Total;

                    listBoxItems.Items.Add(item);

                    GrandTotal = GrandTotal + item.Total;
                    TotalDiscount = TotalDiscount + item.DiscountAmount;
                    TotalTaxAmount = TotalTaxAmount + item.GGSTAmount;

                    order.GrandTotal = GrandTotal;
                    order.TotalDiscount = TotalDiscount;
                    order.TaxAmount = TotalTaxAmount;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            item.Quantity = 1;
            item.Total = item.GrossPricePerUnit * item.Quantity;
            item.DiscountAmount = item.DiscountAmount * item.Quantity;
            item.GGSTAmount = (item.SGSTAmount + item.CGSTAmount) * item.Quantity;
            item.ItemTitleWithQtyPrice = item.ItemTitle + " Quantity " + item.Quantity + " Total Price: ₹ " + item.Total;

            listBoxItems.Items.Add(item);

            GrandTotal = GrandTotal + item.Total;
            TotalDiscount = TotalDiscount + item.DiscountAmount;
            TotalTaxAmount = TotalTaxAmount + item.GGSTAmount;

            order.GrandTotal = GrandTotal;
            order.TotalDiscount = TotalDiscount;
            order.TaxAmount = TotalTaxAmount;
        }

        txtTotalDiscounts.Text = order.TotalDiscount.ToString();
        txtGrandTotal.Text = order.GrandTotal.ToString();

        //// BIND TO DATA SOURCE DATAGRIDVIEW
        //var bindingList = new BindingList<OrderItem>(items);
        //var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
        //dGridViewOrderedItems.DataSource = source;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There maybe several issues in your code but you give more detail about it.But If Quantity is not showing as updating in listBox then try for following code which is updated for you in your sense.This code is not tested check and give feedback about it.

```
item.ItemTitleWithQtyPrice = item.ItemTitle + " Quantity " + it.Quantity + " Total Price: ₹ " + item.Total;
```

and one more thing suggest you to add break; point in your search loop check because one item that you are searching or use the concept of Linq for finding by ID.

Comment: Thank you but you have pasted the exact same code I already have in mine if you can please check.

Comment: you check it's different of it.Quantity